# Anonymous iOS App star rating

Tags: ios-appstore

Will any identifiable information about my account be displayed to the developer or owner of the App I rate with a star rating (not a written review)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**.

In case of star rating, no personally identifiable information is shared with the developer.

In fact the developer is not even able to see the individual star rating, only an aggregated rating after a minimum number of reviews are made.